# Disable PHP Execution in a directory (using Nginx)

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, websecurity

I came across solutions to block executables but only by using .htaccess file in the directory.

```
# Block executables
<FilesMatch "\.(php|phtml|php3|php4|php5|pl|py|jsp|asp|html|htm|shtml|sh|cgi|suspected)$">
    deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

How can I achieve the same thing if I only have Nginx and not apache2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The block for Nginx will be as follows.
This rule implies that file with any extension in the below list will not be executed.

```
location /home/username/public_html/wp-content/uploads {
    location ~* \.(php|phtml|php3|php4|php5|pl|py|jsp|asp|html|htm|shtml|sh|cgi|suspected)$ {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i'm very new to nginx. could you please update your solution to work with this directory (and all its subdirectories) : /public_html/wp-content/uploads

Comment: You would have to specify the full path of the uploads directory. I presume its under some /home directory. So just add the /home/username/public_html/wp-content/uploads path to the location directive. I have added the above. You will need to replace the username with the actual one.